# Issue with script using lastest fb sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm having problems with the following code, which keeps on displaying:

PHP message: 
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Method Facebook\Entities\AccessToken::__toString() 
must return a string value in /usr/share/nginx/html/sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php

```
<?php

require 'sdk/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;


$authToken = appid|sercet

$session = new FacebookSession($_GET['$authToken']);

$request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'GET',
        '/padgeid/statuses');

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */

?>
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Have you set your acces token?

Comment: try this: Facebook::setAccessToken('access-token');, and try to google first before asking on SO, google gives you the answer in 80% of the cases, and if google cant help, then ask SO.

Comment: Yes, I have been searching for a while and nothing works. I have also tried the Facebook::setAccessToken and it doesn't exist?

Comment: Hmm lookup the facebook API documentation on how to set your acces token?

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that whatever it's receiving for an access token isn't in string format (or badly formatted)

Since you are adding your appid and secret you should just set the Default Session as such

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID','APP_SECRET')
```

Then at this point you need to decide whether you are getting the token from the `$_GET` which seems incredibly insecure or the variable you set `$authToken = appid|sercet`

The easiest will be to just set it directly into the session

```
$session = new FacebookSession('APP_ID|APP_SECRET')
```

After that you are trying to retrieve page statuses with an application but this isn't possible you will receive an OAuth error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Requires user session", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

So you should be using `/page_id/posts` here or a user access token.